# reverse number for max unsigned int

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I try to write a program for reverse the user input number.

The user input range is from 0 < a < 4294967295,
here is **EDITED** code.

```
unsigned long int reverseNumber(unsigned long int num)
{
    unsigned long int rev = 0;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        rev = rev *10 + (num%10);
        num = num/10;
    }

    return rev;
}
```

The problem is when I input 4294967295, it will output 1632727628.
Why? I have no idea why it happened. 
How can I reverse the 4294967295.

I had changed it to unsigned long int, printf by using %lu, but still output 1632727628. Why?

Comment: an integer overflow is occurring

Comment: Just convert int to a char array and print it from end to begin.

Comment: But I change it to unsigned long int, it still output the same answer. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse of 4294967295 is 5927694924, which is greater than 4294967295, which is the greatest integer which can be stored on 32 bit.

Comment: But I change it to unsigned long int, it still output the same answer. Why?

Comment: @user2301281 Because `unsigned long int` is 32 bit as well. You need to change to `unsigned long long int`, it is 64bit.

Comment: No, I change to unsigned long long int it output 547093574220.

Comment: @user2301281 Did you changed it everywhere?

Comment: @user2301281 I've just tried your code and it works by me without any problem. Maybe there is another bug somewhere in the code which you didn't include (maybe around your scanf).

Comment: I find out the bug, I forget to assign array as unsigned long long int. Sorry and Thanks. =D

Answer (score 7):

The reverse of `4294967295` is `5927694924` which is greater than the range of `unsigned int`

In your system, `unsigned int` is `32-bit` wide, hence the max value that an `unsigned int` can represent is `4294967295` i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`. That is why your result is overflowing and whatever remains in `32` bits is shown as output.

If you represent `5927694924` in hex, it is `0x16151724C` which has extra `33rd` bit `1`, which is discarded and hence output is `0x6151724C` which is `1632727628` in decimal.

To print it on screen you need a greater data type like `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t` or `unsigned long` (on 64-bit systems only), whatever your compiler supports for `64` bit integers.

Comment: No, it is not just simple subtraction (In this case however, the result may be same). It is modulus actually i.e. `5927694924 % 4294967295`.

Comment: But I change it to unsigned long int, it still output the same answer. Why?

Comment: @MattMcNabb : Can't edit my comment now but I got your point.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is when I input 4294967295, it will output 1632727628. Why?

`unsigned int` can store `2^32-1` max. The reverse of `4294967295` is `5927694924` which is much bigger than `2^32-1`. Hence the out put is `1632727628`. `1632727628` is in fact `5927694924 % 4294967296`

To solve this you should have used `unsigned long it`. But again if the number is great than highest long it'll overflow again.

Comment: only true for 32 bit systems

Comment: But I change it to unsigned long int, it still output the same answer. Why?

Comment: @user2301281 Because `unsigned long` is usually the same thing as `unsigned int`